# HTTP connection failure when calling local API from .Net MAUI view

Tags: android-emulator, backend, maui, httpurlconnection, refit

When calling my locally hosted API from my android emulator's .NET MAUI app, I receive an error message stating that the HTTP connection failed.

I am able to successfully send requests to my local API via google chrome on the android emulator, but when attempting to hit the same URL in the application, I receive a connection failure error.

I am using "http://10.0.2.2:5223" as the base URL for my HTTP client, and I am also using Refit to create the RestService within the .NET MAUI app.

Is it possible to create an HTTP client within a .NET MAUI ContentPage, and then use it to retrieve data from the API? My team is using C# Markup for views, so I thought it would be straightforward to create the client and call our API from the C# Markup view.

I have attached the code for the view in which I created the client and attempted an API call,

```
internal class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private int _selectedTabIndex { get; set; } = 1;
    private IAPIClient _client { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        _client = RestService.For<IAPIClient>("http://10.0.2.2:5223");
        new Action(async () => await LoadData())();

        Build();
#if DEBUG
        HotReloadService.UpdateApplicationEvent += ReloadUI;
#endif
    }

    async Task LoadData()
    {
        var user = await _client.GetUser();
    }

    ...
}
```

and the code for the Refit client

```
public interface IAPIClient
{
    [Get("/User")]
    Task<UserModel> GetUser();
}
```

Really perplexed as to why I am unable to establish a connection to the API, and feel that I am misunderstanding some fundamentals about .NET MAUI. Would I need a ViewModel to faciliate this process? And if so, why?

Would really appreciate some feedback/guidance here, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide any log information about the connection failure error? You can also try to use [breakpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2022) to check which line code caused error.

Answer (score 2):

May be your issue is about the security setting on Android device.
Add the parameter `UsesCleartextTraffic = true on [Application]`

MainApplication.cs (in the folder Platforms/Android)

```
namespace MauiApp1
{
    [Application(UsesCleartextTraffic =true)]
    public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
}
```